# Putting load into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, load

a quick question, how can I put the content of a loaded file into a JavaScript variable?

```
function myfunc(){
    $('.layer').load('content.txt');
}
```

I can access it with div class="layer", of course, but how can I also pass the result to a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this is what you want:

```
var content = "";
$('.layer').load("./content.txt", function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    content = responseText;

    /* do stuff with content */
});
```

Comment: I tried to get the content with alert(content); then, the alert is empty.

Comment: Try alerting out the `textStatus` variable to see what the status is. Also look at your console to see if the request was successful.

Comment: Same thing, when I'm trying to get an alert with the textStatus. The console isn't showing anything.

Comment: Did you examine the request in the Net tab?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer:

```
var plainText = $('.layer').content();
```